# WAMP change folder path not changing

Tags: apache, path, wamp, directory

I used this article to change the www folder path:

http://techmehow.org/howto/sync-wamp-dropbox/

It works on one computer but on this one it does not change my folder path. I change these two in the Apache httpdconf.ini.

```
DocumentRoot "c:/Dropbox/wamp/www/"

<Directory "c:/Dropbox/wamp/www/">
```

Even if it now says it should use my dropbox folder, it still uses my old wamp path which is:

```
c:/wamp/www/
```

Why does it not use the dropbox? What more can I try to make it work? I have "Restarted all services" multiple times, no luck.

**Apache version:** 2.4.9

**Update**

When going to localhost in the browser it lists the folders in my dropbox www BUT when clicking on the localhost/some_site/ it uses the old path.

Comment: You would have to manually make the same changes to httpd.conf on the second PC the same ones you did on the first PC.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a better solution for using dropbox with WAMPServer.

First uninstall WAMPServer from both machines ( backup if you have work you want to keep )

You should have Dropbox installed on both PC's of course, but they should also be installed so the dropbox folder is in the EXACT same location on both PC's eg `C:\dropbox`.

So on PC1, install WAMPServer into `C:\dropbox\wamp`, you get a dialog asking where to install it. Once installed dont change any configurations, just prove it works.

On PC2, fire up Dropbox, this should sync PC2::C:\Dropbox so it contains the `wamp` folder and all subfolders.

Now take a shortcut of `C:\Dropbox\wamp\wampmanager.exe` and place it on your desktop.

Run WAMPServer from this new icon. It will probably stay red as the Apache and MySQL services have not been registered with Windows yet on PC2.

Do this to register them, using the wampmanager menus...

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service
wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Install Service
```

*Things to check first*

Make sure you have all the required MSVC C/C++ runtime libraries installed on both PC's before starting this process.

**Cavetas and Warnings**

Using Dropbox with any MySQL environment is only a valid approach if **ONLY ONE** person is working on it at any one time. So its fine if, for example, you work on the project at the office, then close WAMPServer ( to make sure MySQL closes and flushes all buffers) and Dropbox after all syncing is complete.

Then go home, open up dropbox to sync the changes you made at the office, and then continue development. When done, close WAMPServer and dropbox. Then go back to the office.... etc etc

If you believe this will allow 2 or more people to work on the same project at the same time **DONT**. It will cause disaster!

Why? Well imagine the senario where 2 people both update a table. The same disk file gets changed on PC1 and PC2, dropbox syncs PC1 to the server, PC2 also tries to sync the same file to the server. **BANG** Who's changes are kept. Probably the best result is that you get lots of *conflicted copies*, and they are difficult enough to sort out if the contents are TEXT, so its basically impossible for a MySQL database file. The worst result is somebodies updates are lost.

This gets even worse if you are using an INNODB database as all tables plus various control structures are stored, by default, in the same physical file.